# Scheduled messages

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, message-queue, mq

Which message queue library can process scheduled messages?

For example:
I need to put mail in queue by ASP.NET MVC application and send emails by schedule. For each email I have date and time of sending.

1. message1 at 10/09/2012 12:00
2. message2 at 10/10/2012 13:35
3. message3 at 10/10/2012 24:00

Answer (score 2):

Sounds more like something that would be done with a **scheduled task**.  For that there are several mature options beside accessing the native api that you could use:

[Task Scheduler Managed Wrapper](http://taskscheduler.codeplex.com/)

[Quartz.NET](http://quartznet.sourceforge.net/)

Of course your task may process a queue.